# Are there something like "flag banned" for many declined flags?

Tags: support, flags, flag-ban

I can't find the answer in the help center. Is there any flag ban for many declined or disputed flags? If so, how many declined flags are needed to get banned?

For example, I have 233 helpful flags and 9 declined/disputed flags. How much more declined flags I needed to get banned?

Comment: Yes, it's all explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/152859). (temporary ban only, up to one week)